# Can a raw-food diet allow someone to "switch" from one side of his brain to the other when he gets tired?

Tags: natural-remedies, sleep

The following article relates this claim by someone who stayed awake for 11 days:

[How can someone stay awake for 11 days?](http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/sleep-deprivation.htm)

> He also employed a unique raw-food diet. Wright claims that his
>   regimen of salads, avocados, bananas, pineapples, nuts, seeds, carrot
>   juice and herbal tea helped his brain stay awake. He also says that it
>   allowed him to "switch" from one side of his brain to the other when
>   he got tired.
>
> (Whales and dolphins are known to employ similar brain-switching techniques, which allow one part of their brain to rest while the other focuses on breathing and other basic functions.)

Can a raw-food diet allow someone to "switch" from one side of his brain to the other when he gets tired?

Comment: this is a must try, I will try it eventually I can guarantee that.

Comment: Humans have specialized centers in the brain, specialization has occurred between the two hemispheres, for example speech is exclusive to the left side of the brain, although Broca's area on the right side shows some corresponding activity. If he's functioning only on the right side, then he wouldn't be able to speak. Weirdly I have experienced this after a 300 mile (480 Km) motorbike journey - I was functioning perfectly, but when I arrived I was completely unable to speak to my then GF. Some of my brain was definitley asleep.